# Tensorflow.keras: AlreadyExistsError

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.x

I am building a model using tensorflow. I trained my model and it worked normally. Then, I modified my code and when I try to train my model, I am getting a AlreadyExistError. I restart my Jupyter Notebook but I’m still getting the same error. I need some help please.
here is my piece of code where I build the network and train it. The problem occurs in the last line.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, Dropout, Dense, Flatten, LSTM, MaxPooling1D, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, TensorBoard

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same',
                 input_shape=(vector_size, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='elu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(512, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.3)))

model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)

model.summary()
model.fit(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=no_epochs,
         validation_data=(np.array(x_test), np.array(y_test)),  callbacks=[tensorboard, EarlyStopping(min_delta=0.0001, patience=3)])
```

> Train on 90000 samples, validate on 10000 samples Epoch 1/10
>   500/90000 [..............................] - ETA: 2:00:49
>   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py:846:
>   RuntimeWarning: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which
>   is not available. Available metrics are:    (self.monitor,
>   ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AlreadyExistsError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 model.fit(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=no_epochs,
>   ----> 2          validation_data=(np.array(x_test), np.array(y_test)),  callbacks=[tensorboard, EarlyStopping(min_delta=0.0001, patience=3)])
>         3 print('You can continue')
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
>   **kwargs)
>       817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       818         workers=workers,
>   --> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       820 
>       821   def evaluate(self,
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py
>   in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
>   **kwargs)
>       340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
>       341                 training_context=training_context,
>   --> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
>       343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>       344
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py
>   in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size,
>   batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode,
>   training_context, total_epochs)
>       126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
>       127       try:
>   --> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
>       129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
>       130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py
>   in execution_function(input_fn)
>        96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
>        97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
>   ---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
>        99 
>       100   return execution_function
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
>       566         xla_context.Exit()
>       567     else:
>   --> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
>       569 
>       570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
>   in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
>       630         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
>       631         # stateless function.
>   --> 632         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
>       633     else:
>       634       canon_args, canon_kwds = \
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)    2361     with self._lock:
>   2362       graph_function, args, kwargs =
>   self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
>   -> 2363     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access    2364     2365   @property
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
>   in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)    1609          if
>   isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,    1610
>   resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
>   -> 1611         self.captured_inputs)    1612     1613   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
>   in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
>   1690       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
>   1691       return
>   self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
>   -> 1692           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))    1693
>   forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
>   1694         args,
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
>   in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
>       543               inputs=args,
>       544               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
>   --> 545               ctx=ctx)
>       546         else:
>       547           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py
>   in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
>        65     else:
>        66       message = e.message
>   ---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
>        68   except TypeError as e:
>        69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value,
>   from_value)
>
> AlreadyExistsError:  Resource
>   __per_step_0/sequential/bidirectional/forward_lstm/while_grad/body/_429/gradients/AddN_13/tmp_var/N10tensorflow19TemporaryVariableOp6TmpVarE
>      [[{{node
>   sequential/bidirectional/forward_lstm/while_grad/body/_429/gradients/AddN_13/tmp_var}}]]
>   [Op:__inference_distributed_function_12060]
>
> Function call stack: distributed_function

Comment: Can you give the error stack trace ?

Comment: I added it by modifying the post

Answer (score 1):

You must have a problem on same architectures from previous run being seen while training.

This should reset the keras session :

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend
backend.clear_session()
```

Comment: I downgraded my TF version to TF 2.0.0 and it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the problem when using EMR on AWS, and I solved just uninstalling Keras, if you have tensorflow you already have Keras, but there are other packages that depends of the old Keras library. So you need to uninstall the old Keras to avoid this problem.

!pip uninstall keras

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as the previous answer, what happened with me is that I already had Tensorflow installed via the command prompt in Windows, so there was no need to use the command import anymore in my Jupyter Notebook. And also this installation command can/should only appear once (preferably at the top of your program). To verify that you have it already (if you use Anaconda for example) is to go to the environment tab and on the right-hand side of the screen, look under the register 'installed' if TensorFlow is on the list. Since it was the case in my situation, I just went ahead and didn't try anymore to import TensorFlow.