# Error importing Keras: AlreadyExistsError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm unable to import Keras in a fresh shell or when importing to a Python script. Importing produces the below error (full shell output shown for context, ignore the CUDA error):

```sh
$ python
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul  3 2021, 17:50:42)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
2021-08-17 11:07:32.559476: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
2021-08-17 11:07:32.559495: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-08-17 11:07:33.255954: E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/api/keras/dropout/temp_rate_is_zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras import metrics as metrics_module
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras import activations
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/activations.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.layers import advanced_activations
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing import CenterCrop
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py", line 24, in <module>
    from keras.preprocessing import image as image_preprocessing
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras.utils import all_utils as utils
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/all_utils.py", line 34, in <module>
    from keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.layers.core import Lambda
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/core/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from keras.layers.core.dropout import Dropout
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/core/dropout.py", line 26, in <module>
    keras_temporary_dropout_rate = tf.__internal__.monitoring.BoolGauge(
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/monitoring.py", line 360, in __init__
    super(BoolGauge, self).__init__('BoolGauge', _bool_gauge_methods,
  File "<venv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/monitoring.py", line 135, in __init__
    self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.
```

I saw [Error importing tensorflow "AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012741/error-importing-tensorflow-alreadyexistserror-another-metric-with-the-same-nam), but this is reproducible in a fresh shell with no prior imports, so that fix doesn't apply.

I also saw [Tensorflow.keras: AlreadyExistsError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269982/tensorflow-keras-alreadyexistserror), but I am unable to even import keras, much less import and run that command.

This persists through re-logs and reboots, and has been reproduced on multiple machines. This issue occurs in a venv and in the system python environment. I was able to resolve this switching from `tensorflow==2.6.0` to `tf-nightly==2.7.0dev20210812`, but this prefer to not use one of the nightly builds if possible.

On all machines, I was able to successfully use `tensorflow==2.6.0` when  first installed, this issue has only popped up after it has been in use for a while.

I have seen this on multiple python versions from 3.7 to 3.9. Currently this is running in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You should not use/import `keras` directly. `import tensorflow as tf` and use `tf.keras` instead. Likely you have an old keras version installed which is incompatible with the new TF versions (but this is just speculation).

Comment: @xdurch0 That's what I normally use, I'm just using the shorthand while trying to resolve this issue. It produces the same error either way

Comment: The issue could be due to multiple versions of tensorflow or version mismatch of tensorflow and keras.
You can try creating new venv and try again, if you get the issue again then you can create the bug [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).